# JSON Parsing in Titanium App (Multidimensional array)

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, titanium-mobile

I want to parse a multidimensional array in Titanium.

It is something like this:-

```
{"nodes":
    [{"node":
       {
        "title":"<a href=\"\/adf\/into-the-blue\">Into the Blue<\/a>",
        "Teaser":"Into the Blue Teaser.",
        "Knowledge":"<a href=fsdf">Americas<\/a>",
         ...
         ...
```

This is what I did. (It only gets the first row :( )

// url has the JSON URL.

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function() {
    var response = xhr.responseText;
    var resultObj = JSON.parse(response);
    Ti.API.log("The Response is " + response);
    Ti.API.log("THE RESULT " + resultObj);
    updateBanners(resultObj);
    updateTable(resultObj, catid, catregion, cattopic, listByDate);
};
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

Many Thanks

Comment: If you debug the application and place a break after the var resultObj=JSON.parse(response); line and then look at the result in the debugger's watch window, does it show all your data in there?  Are you sure the problem is with the JSON and not your updateBanners() and updateTable() functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to solve it.

```
//Correct Response. Gives the total number of returned Records.
resultObj.nodes.length

 // and for a specific title of first row.

 resultObj.nodes[0].node["title"]

alert("Total Records are :- "+ responseObjArr.nodes.length + " and the 1st Title is:- " + responseObjArr.nodes[0].node["title"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing a piece from the parsing.

```
var resultObj = JSON.parse(response);
```

Mine usually looks like.

```
var resultObj = JSON.parse(response).NameOfMyRemoteFunctionResult;
```

I use WCF web service for my calls, so this is the type of response I get back.